# APNS error Warning: stream_socket_client() error

Tags: php, sockets, push, push-notification, ssl-certificate

I am working hard on it and openssl is enabled on my server but issue remains as it. Will it make any difference if run it MAc book. Please response if it is done there.

**My Code:**

```
<?php
$deviceToken = 'my device key';  // not putting in for security

$payload['aps'] = array('alert' => 'This is the alert text', 'badge' => 1, 'sound' => 'default');
$payload = json_encode($payload);

$apnsHost = 'gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com';
$apnsPort = 2195;
$apnsCert = 'apns-dev.pem';

$streamContext = stream_context_create();
stream_context_set_option($streamContext, 'ssl', 'local_cert', $apnsCert);

$apns = stream_socket_client('ssl://' . $apnsHost . ':' . $apnsPort, $error, $errorString, 2, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT, $streamContext);

$apnsMessage = chr(0) . chr(0) . chr(32) . pack('H*', str_replace(' ', '', $deviceToken)) . chr(0) . chr(strlen($payload)) . $payload;
fwrite($apns, $apnsMessage);

socket_close($apns);
fclose($apns);
?>
```

**Error:**

> Warning: stream_socket_client() [function.stream-socket-client]: SSL
>   operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
>   error:14094410:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:sslv3 alert handshake
>   failure in F:\xampp\htdocs\apns\apns.php on line 24
>
> Warning: stream_socket_client() [function.stream-socket-client]:
>   Failed to enable crypto in F:\xampp\htdocs\apns\apns.php on line 24
>
> Warning: stream_socket_client() [function.stream-socket-client]:
>   unable to connect to ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195
>   (Unknown error) in F:\xampp\htdocs\apns\apns.php on line 24

Please post if any have an idea.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. The solution for me was generate the certificate again. I did it with these commands:

```
openssl x509 -in testpush_aps_development.cer -inform der -out TestPushCert.pem
openssl pkcs12 -nocerts -out TestPushKey.pem -in TestPush.p12
```

After that:

```
cat TestPushKey.pem TestPushCert.pem > TestPushCK.pem
```

Remember that testpush_aps_development.cer in this case is the certificate that you have in your apple developer page in the section APNS Certificates.

Hope this help you, anyway I'm sure it's a problem with the certificates.

Answer (score 0):

Check your certificates, they cause errors quite oftenly.

Comment: I run into the same problem. The certificate should be correct (contains the cert and private key). If I remove the certificate file, I get a different error (unable to set private key). So it's probably not a certification failure, is it?